# How are these two optimization problems equivalent?

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm trying to show that the two problems are equivalent

> Let $\Bbb A = \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ where $A_i \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$
>
> Then
>
> $$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \max_{i=1, \dots, k} \|A_ix - b\|$$
>
> is equivalent to
>
> $$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \space \sup \{\|Ax - b\| \mid A \in \text{conv}(A_1, \dots,
>  A_n)\}$$
>
> Where $\text{conv}$ is the convex hull.

I know that two problems are equivalent when from the solution from one you can find the solution of the other, but I'm having trouble seeing how to show this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure in which variable you want to minimize. In $x$, in $b$ or in $(x,b)$?

Comment: The variable is $x$, I have edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every element in $A\in\operatorname{conv}(A_1,\dots,A_k)$ can be written as $A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i A_i$, where $\lambda_i\in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1} \lambda_i = 1$. In particular we also have $b = \sum_{i=1} \lambda_i b$. Consequently we obtain the following inequality
\begin{align}
\|Ax - b\| &= \Big\|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i A_i x -\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i b\Big\|
=\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(A_ix-b)\Big\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\|A_i x-b\|\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \max_{i=1,\dots,k}\|A_i x-b\| = \max_{i=1,\dots,k}\|A_i x-b\|
\end{align}
for arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$.
One immediate consequence is
$$
\sup_{A\in\operatorname{conv}(A_1,\dots,A_k)} \|Ax - b\| \leq \max_{i=1,\dots,k}\|A_i x-b\|.
$$
On the other hand since every $A_i \in \operatorname{conv}(A_1,\dots,A_k)$ we also have
$$
\sup_{A\in\operatorname{conv}(A_1,\dots,A_k)} \|Ax - b\| \geq \max_{i=1,\dots,k}\|A_i x-b\|.
$$
Hence, we have equality. Clearly this won't change if we minimize over $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

So this has nothing to do with the minimization problem. In fact this is the key essence of the simplex algorithm.